# Multiple columns on IN operator not working

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

According to the Databricks docs, this should work, though the docs do not include an example using column names in the IN operator.

```
select *
from table_1
where (column1,column2,column3) IN (
('foo','bar','2023-01-01'),
('one','two','2023-01-02')
)
```

But it results in error: cannot resolve '(named_struct('column1'...

Should this work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer further down in the error message...this is supported only if all of the columns are the same type. So the last column could be cast to string.

```
select *
from table_1
where (column1,column2,cast(column3 as string)) IN (
('foo','bar','2023-01-01'),
('one','two','2023-01-02')
)
```